# Do each of the races in Guild Wars 2 have their own starting location?

Tags: guild-wars-2

Is the starting point for new chars the same for all races, or is it more like WOW where every race has their own spawn point?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Every race has its own starting area. Additionally, race is a factor in the personal story of a character, thus it affects not only your starting quests, but part of those that come later as well.

Edit: You can, however, travel to the other races' starting locations starting *very* early in your character's lifetime, and the questless paradigm GW2 is built on means you can accompany your friends anywhere you all want to go; only each character's personal story is going to be location specific.

Comment: Nice one, will probably go for the same race just to skip the travel to the other starting area :)

Comment: From the beta weekend not too long ago i remember it being quite easy to travel to the other areas, takes just a minute + some loading time. However, personal quests will still be in the other areas.

Comment: Your race will also affect which member of the 'Edge of Destiny' your story interacts with primarily.

Answer (score 3):

It is not the same - the first choice in creating a character is choosing their race - and that also [determines the starting location](http://gw2.seartipy.com/starting-zones-of-all-guild-wars-2-races/), which is different for each race.